# header information is missing from image, after writing using opencv

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis, digital-image-processing, geotiff-tiff

I am doing complement of an image using open-cv python, while writing the image, open-cv is not writing the header information in the complemented image. my image data are in TIFF format.

i am doing like this...

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.tiff", -1)
for i in xrange(0, len(img)):
    for j in xrange(0, len(i)):
      img[i][j] = 65535-img[i][j]
cv2.imwrite("complemented.tif", img)
```